# query a dictionary for unique generic objects

Tags: c#, generics, generic-collections

I am trying to write a generic method that returns a generic object. The method will take the generic type and use it to query a collection, for the object with the matching type.

I have made an attempt but there is a compilation error, when trying to add this object to a collection. `cannot convert from CustomSet<AppLog>' to 'CustomSet<System.Type>'`

How can I meet this specification?

```
public CustomSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    Type key = typeof(TEntity);

    if (allSets.ContainsKey (key))
    {
        return allSets[key];
    }
}

private static readonly Dictionary<Type, CustomSet<Type>> allSets = new Dictionary<Type, CustomSet<Type>>()
{
    {typeof(AppLog), AppLogs}
};

public static CustomSet<AppLog> AppLogs { get; set; }
```

***EDIT***

code updated so that only the mentioned compilation error will be present

Comment: this may work: `private static readonly Dictionary<Type, CustomSet<Type>> allSets = new Dictionary<typeof(AppLog), CustomSet<AppLog>>().Add(typeof(AppLog), AppLogs);`

Comment: @FarzanMirheydari - That code doesn't compile.

Comment: Ive updated the snippet. Only the compilation error mention will be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need your `appSets` dictionary to be less type-safe to achieve that. Define it as `Dictionary<Type, object>` and cast the item back to `CustomSet<TEntity>` after retrieving:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> allSets = new Dictionary<Type, object>.Add(typeof(AppLog), AppLogs);

public CustomSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    Type key = typeof (TEntity);       

    if (allSets.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return (CustomSet<TEntity>)allSets[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good with some slight modifications. I just realised that using `TEntity` as argument is not valid. only a Type variable of `TEntity` can be passed. I will make an edit to the question and, if you make this slight change to your answer, I will accept it.